# Is it good idea call third party services from axon aggregate

Tags: spring, axon

I have an axon aggregate. It handle command and before applying event has to invoke third party service for validation some parameters, according to this validation i apply events or not. Is it good practice? Or I have make validation before i send command?

```
@Aggregate
public class SomeAggregate {
[...]
   @CommandHandler
   public void someHandler() {
     if(thirdPartyService.invoke) {
       apply(...)
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a non-blocking (domain) service, something like a finite state machine, it's okay to call from within the aggregate, since it's most likely going to finish soon.
However, 'third party service' to me sounds like an outbound call, which might take some time.

When Axon loads an aggregate, it blocks the aggregate so no other thread can change it's state/handle commands on it.
A third-party service would mean that the aggregate is blocked even longer.

Hence, I would suggest not calling a third party service in your aggregate.
Either call the service prior to entering the aggregate or perform a compensating action after command handling was finalized to revert the decision. Which of the two makes most sense in your scenario, is dependent on your domain. I see "pre-validation" through the third-party service however as the most reasonable option to take.

Comment: Happy to have been of help! :-)

Comment: The last sentence is incomplete did you mean to finish it this way?

> Either call the service prior to entering the aggregate

or in an @EventHandler after the initial command? I've built a solution the way, but I'm unsure if that complexity could not be reduced with external command handlers or UnitOfWork "tricks"...

Comment: Good point @kossmoboleat, I've just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If your third party service has side effects and isn't idempotent then I'm not sure what to do (I'm still trying to figure it out).

If it does have side effects, then I would want the aggregate to block / lock and use the aggregate's state / history to carefully manage such an interaction like this

```
@Aggregate
public class SomeAggregate {
[...]
   @CommandHandler
   public void someHandler() {
    /*
        Reason about whether its appropriate to send a request. 
        e.g. if a request has been sent but no response has been received,
        then depending on the third party service it might be in an indeterminate state.
        Instead of trying to interact with it, it might be better 
        to notify someone instead. 
    */
    rejectIfNotSafe()      

     /*
         Effectively locks this interaction / any other instances in the same path
         should get a concurrent modification exception when trying to commit this event.
     */
     commit(new ThirdPartyServiceRequested())

     if(thirdPartyService.invoke) {
       apply(...)
     }
   }
}
```

But Axon's 'unit of work' means that the emitted events won't be published / committed until the command handler has completed, so we can't guard is this manner.

Any ideas?